how to get the position of each point for "instance on points" using python
I have a collection called "A" with some objects in it. Now I'm trying to make the objects in A randomly distribute follow a curve "C".
I'm trying to use geometry node "instance on points", the instance is the collection objects, and the points is randomly generated by "Set Position" node. Now I want to get each position of the points, because I want to get the bounding box of each object, is it possible to realize it using python?

What do you mean by "get each position" in this context? Get the numbers written down somewhere so they are readable or can be saved in a text file or just get them to be used in some calculations or other positions? Also what means "get the bounding box"? Just place a bounding box on the objects or have bounding boxes as separate objects or get their dimensions written down somehow?

“get each position” means get the position of each points，for example，I have a curve A，and I want to distribute 5 cube along the curve，now I use “sample curve” node and “Set position” node to randomly sample 5 different points as the position of the cube，what I want to get is the coordinates of these 5 points in world coordinate system.

"get bounding box" means get the 3D range of an object. For example, a cube with size (2,2,2), whose origin is at the center of its geometry.
When it is placed at (0,0,0), eight coordinates of its bounding box vertex are (1, 1, 1),(1, 1, -1),(1,-1,1),(1,-1,-1),(-1, 1, 1),(-1, 1, -1),(-1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1).
And when it is placed at (1,0,0), eight  coordinates of its bounding box vertex become(2, 1, 1),(2, 1, -1),(2,-1,1),(2,-1,-1),(0, 1, 1),(0, 1, -1),(0,-1,1),(0,-1,-1).
So the bounding box is related to both the position of the object and the size go the object.

I know what a bounding box is and I know what positions are. I was not asking what positions and bounding boxes means, I was asking what "get" in this context means: do you need them to be plugged into somewhere or do you need a readout of the values so that you can display the numbers?

Thank you very much for your attention to my question. Looking forward to your reply!

Sorry, I misunderstood. What I ultimately want is to make images and labels for object detection task. So I neee to render a picture of objects, and write out the coordinate of each bounding box for each object.

So it will be fine if I can readout the values of the position of each points.
